# how to get column names of a put in hbase?

Tags: hbase

Given a `put` (in shell), user needs to specific which column to add values. Is there a way to obtain all column names a `put` has? I am aware of method `get` as

> public List get(byte[] family,byte[] qualifier)

which however does not give programmer the information about column names.

Comment: What are you looking for, If you want to scan -- you can use scan '$hbase_table_path', it will give you all columns with all column families. If you want  to restrict columnFamilies like cf1,cf2 then u can add another param in scan as  {COLUMNS=>['cf1','cf2']}